# Question on contentEditable onChange event

Tags: javascript, next.js, onchange, contenteditable

I just cloned the nextjs blog starter code and started tweaking some code and made one of the divs contentEditable

```
<p className="card">
  <h3>Documentation &rarr;</h3>
  <ContentEditable onChange = {handleTextChange}
    innerRef={contentEditable}
    html = {transform(localRawData)} 
  />
</p>
```

To support this I have to the following data defined

```
const [localRawData, setLocalRawData] = useState("");
const localMap = new Map();
const contentEditable = React.createRef();
```

I have intentionally kept two local state variables one for raw data and one for processed/transformed data

This is my event handler code

```
const handleTextChange = (event) => {
    localMap.set('key', event.target.value);
    console.log("Retrieval from map", localMap.get('key'));
}
```

The console.log for this code is like this
[image]

What if I want every character to come in like a stream in the event

Something like

- Retrieval from map f
- Retrieval from map u
- Retrieval from map n

Is this even possible ? Is there any onChange equivalent that can get me the last character entered instead of the entire contentEditable on every text change event ?

Comment: Use `onKeyUp` event. In handler call like this `event.key`

Comment: Thanks Faisal but I won't get rich text characters. Like if I change a text to bold the HTML is lost. This certainly helps but I will wait to see if there is a way to get rich text characters and HTML tags in this fashion.